# how does one remove <![CDATA[ ]]> tags from around text in XML using Hpricot?

Tags: ruby, xml, hpricot, xml-parsing

i just want the text out of there with out those tags. Does Hrpicot.XML have any methods for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use element.inner_text instead of #inner_html and it removes them for you

Comment: You probably will want a #inner_text.strip to get rid of the (almost guaranteed) extraneous whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

```
doc.search("*") do |element|
    element.swap element.content if element.kind_of? Hpricot::CData
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
doc = Hpricot::XML(open('http://www.cnn.com/.element/ssi/www/auto/2.0/video/xml/most_popular.xml'))
(doc/:cnn_video/:video).each do |status|
  ['tease_txt'].each do |el|
    puts "#{status.at(el).inner_text}"
  end
end
```

Example output (looks spammy but this is not spam!):

> New Reno air crash video shows impact
>   Teen catches 800-pound gator
>   Resuming careers post 'don't ask' repeal
>   Creepy skirt peepers
>   Bus-sized satellite to hit Earth thi ...
>   'DWTS' cast hits ballroom for first time
>   What caused trainer's death at SeaWorld?
>   What led to Troy Davis clemency denial?